# Cannot connect to Oracle using python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle11g

I just started to learn python and try to connect to oracle 11g, but I always get following error

> cx_Oracle.InternalError: No Oracle error?

Here is my simple script to connect to oracle

```
import cx_Oracle as oracle
con = oracle.connect('user/password@ip:port/service')
```

Already try to look for any reference in other sites including here but can't find the solution. I don't think I have connection issue to oracle, because I use the same PC to connect to oracle using PHP.
Any advise would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your cx_Oracle version? 11g support added in [version 4.3.3](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html?#version-4-3-3)

Comment: At first I'm not download any cx_Oracle package because there are no error during import, so I assume python 3.4 already include cx_Oracle, but since I always find the same error, I download cx_Oracle 5.2.1 and install it, but I still find the same issue even after install and import it.

Comment: Why 5.2.1 when the latest production version is 5.3?  Do you have the Oracle client libraries (the same as you'd need for PHP)?

Answer (score -1):

One thing to keep in mind anytime you work with Oracle is that they use a proprietary connection protocol [TNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_Network_Substrate) (Transparent Network Substrate). 
Therefore, you might need to use the `cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)` method and then pass it to `cx_Oracle.connect()` method to create your connection. Thus the general format on how to set up Oracle connection is:

```
import cx_Oracle

ip = 'xxx.xxx.xx.xxx'
port = 'xxxx'
SID = 'SID'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
db = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, dsn_tns)
```

This is assuming you have already gotten cx_Oracle to work and import properly, which can be finicky depending on your environment.

Comment: You don't 'need' to use `makedsn`, but it can help.  At the other extreme from `makedsn` is using a hardcoded connection string like `username/password@hostname/servicename`, see, for example, https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ScrollableCursors.py#L23  One final note is that SIDs have been obsolete for a long time.  Use a service name instead.  Check the `makedsn` doc for your version of cx_Oracle: http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html

Comment: @ChristopherJones not sure why the -1 since the answer isn't wrong but I've edited it anyway.

Comment: You still reference SIDs, which were obsoleted a LONG time ago.  Hopefully we can get current, best practice info filtering to the top.